# Best practice to mark deprecated code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, deprecated

I'd like to mark a method as deprecated, so the people using it can easily check their code and catch up. In Java you set @Deprecated and everybody knows what this means.

So is there a preferred way (or even tools) to mark and check for deprecations in Ruby?

Comment: To be fair, Java's annotation sucks, as it has no value to point to a potential replacement

Comment: @HeikoRupp  I know this is 8 years late, but this sort of comment isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

For almost all cases, depending on a library or metaprogramming for a deprecation is overkill.  Just add a comment to the rdoc and call the `Kernel#warn` method.  For example:

```
class Foo
  # <b>DEPRECATED:</b> Please use <tt>useful</tt> instead.
  def useless
    warn "[DEPRECATION] `useless` is deprecated.  Please use `useful` instead."
    useful
  end

  def useful
    # ...
  end
end
```

---

If you're using [Yard](http://yardoc.org/) instead of [rdoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/), your doc comment should look like this:

```
# @deprecated Please use {#useful} instead
```

Lastly, if you adhere to [tomdoc](http://tomdoc.org/), make your comment look like this:

```
# Deprecated: Please use `useful` instead
```

> *Deprecated: Indicates that the method is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. You SHOULD use this to document methods that were Public but will be removed at the next major version.*

---

Also, **don't forget to remove the deprecated method in some future (and properly [semver](http://semver.org/)'d) release**.  Don't make the same mistakes that the Java libraries did.

Comment: I am not sure it is so much a "mistake" from the Java part, rather a huge backward compatibility issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314540), that blindgaenger might not need to consider for his Ruby code.

Comment: Code is a liability.  The less code you have to maintain the better.  Deprecations are good for temporary backwards compatibility, but over time it becomes cruft.  If people *need* to use retired methods, they should use older versions of your libraries instead.

Comment: Excelent response. I just want add a link to the response where I show the approach that I've used lately, which relies on the Ruby Std Lib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293981/best-practice-to-mark-deprecated-code-in-ruby/23554720#23554720

Comment: @RicardoValeriano I agree, your response should be integrated (or higher voted, or both :) ).

Answer (score 77):

Ruby Standard Library has a module with the warning logic: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Gem/Deprecate.html. I tend to prefer it to maintain my deprecation messages in a "standard" way:

```
# my_file.rb

class MyFile
  extend Gem::Deprecate

  def no_more
    close
  end
  deprecate :no_more, :close, 2015, 5

  def close
    # new logic here
  end
end

MyFile.new.no_more
# => NOTE: MyFile#no_more is deprecated; use close instead. It will be removed on or after 2015-05-01.
# => MyFile#no_more called from my_file.rb:16.
```

Note that with this approach you will gain for free information about where the call took place.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this in standard lib.

Comment: the leading `0` for a numeric literal makes it octal and so should likely be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I deprecated an entire class, and suggested the newer class to be used: `deprecate :initialize, UseThisClassInstead, 2017, 5`

Comment: Great usage example, Jon. Really nice one.

Comment: The previous correct answer has been deprecated and the answer by Ricardo Valueriano should now be used

Comment: Thanks a lot @lime; could you add a link to your source please?

Answer (score 21):

Using `ActiveSupport`:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn('Use presenter instead')
    partner_uid
  end
end
```

Warnings are turned off in production environment by default.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to be mean (under the guile of being helpful) you can print out the first line of the callstack during a warning to let devs know where they are using a deprecated call.

This is mean because **I'm pretty sure it's a performance-hit.**

```
warn Kernel.caller.first + " whatever deprecation message here"
```

When used correctly, this will include the absolute path to the file and line where the deprecated call was used.  More information about Kernel::caller is available [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005929)

Comment: I don't consider this mean. A small performance hit is nicer than having to chase down where the deprecated call was, and much nicer than something breaking when the method is eventually removed.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `ActiveSupport::Deprecation` (available in version 4.0+), as such:

```
require 'active_support/deprecation'
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/deprecation'

class MyGem
  def self.deprecator
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.new('2.0', 'MyGem')
  end

  def old_method
  end

  def new_method
  end

  deprecate old_method: :new_method, deprecator: deprecator
end

MyGem.new.old_method
# => DEPRECATION WARNING: old_method is deprecated and will be removed from MyGem 2.0 (use new_method instead). (called from <main> at file.rb:18)
```

Answer (score 8):

You do have [`libdeprecated-ruby`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libdeprecated-ruby) (2010-2012, not available anymore on rubygem in 2015)

A small library intended to aid developers working with deprecated code.
The idea comes from the '`D`' programming language, where developers can mark certain code as deprecated, and then allow/disallow the ability to execute deprecated code.

```
require 'lib/deprecated.rb'
require 'test/unit'

# this class is used to test the deprecate functionality
class DummyClass
  def monkey
    return true
  end

  deprecate :monkey
end

# we want exceptions for testing here.
Deprecate.set_action(:throw)

class DeprecateTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_set_action

    assert_raise(DeprecatedError) { raise StandardError.new unless DummyClass.new.monkey }

    Deprecate.set_action(proc { |msg| raise DeprecatedError.new("#{msg} is deprecated.") })

    assert_raise(DeprecatedError) { raise StandardError.new unless DummyClass.new.monkey }


    # set to warn and make sure our return values are getting through.
    Deprecate.set_action(:warn)

    assert_nothing_raised(DeprecatedError) { raise StandardError.new unless DummyClass.new.monkey } 
  end
end
```

Comment: The link takes me to a page about a Debian package.  This seems similar (if not the same) and is a RubyGem:  https://rubygems.org/gems/deprecated

Answer (score 3):

You can use Class Macros pattern and write something like this:

```
class Module     
     def deprecate(old_method, new_method)
          define_method(old_method) do |*args, &block|
               warn "Method #{old_method}() depricated. Use #{new_method}() instead"
               send(new_method, *args, &block)
          end
     end
end


class Test
     def my_new_method
          p "My method"
     end

     deprecate :my_old_method, :my_method
end
```

Answer (score 3):

When using rails, you have the Module#deprecate method.

Answer (score 2):

[Canivete](http://github.com/qmx/canivete) is a gem which enables you to deprecate your methods in simple and elegant way. A little more about it [here](http://www.diegocarrion.com/2010/05/27/ruby-annotations/).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up throwing together a lightweight method:

```
def deprecate(msg)
  method = caller_locations(1, 1).first.label
  source = caller(2, 1).first
  warn "#{method} is deprecated: #{msg}\ncalled at #{source}"
end
```

Then to deprecate a method insert a call in the method body (or a constructor for a class)

```
def foo
  deprecate 'prefer bar, will be removed in version 3'
  ...
end
```

It's fairly declarative and provides logging with relevant info. I'm not much of a Rubyist so it may need some tweaking/YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

We can use internal macros methods.
Example:

`class Foo
    def get_a; puts "I'm an A" end
    def get_b; puts "I'm an B" end
    def get_c; puts "I'm an C" end`

```
def self.deprecate(old_method, new_method)
  define_method(old_method) do |*args, &block|
     puts "Warning: #{old_method} is deprecated! Use #{new_method} instead"
     send(new_method, *args, &block)
```

end
   end

deprecate :a, :get_a
   deprecate :b, :get_b
   deprecate :c, :get_c
end

o = Foo.new
p o.a