# When are API methods marked "deprecated" actually going to go away?

Tags: java, date

I'm code reviewing a change one of my co-workers just did, and he added a bunch of calls to `Date.toMonth()`, `Date.toYear()` and other deprecated `Date` methods.  All these methods were deprecated in JDK 1.1, but he insists that it's ok to use them because they haven't gone away yet (we're using JDK 1.5) and I'm saying they might go away any day now and he should use `Calendar` methods.

Has Sun/Oracle actually said when these things are going away, or does `@deprecated` just mean you lose style points?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Regarding the APIs, ... it is not specified they will be removed anytime soon.

[Incompatibilities in J2SE 5.0 (since 1.4.2)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/compatibility.html):

Source Compatibility

> [...]
>   In general, the policy is as follows, except for any incompatibilities listed further below:
>
> Deprecated APIs are interfaces that are supported only for backwards compatibility. The javac compiler generates a warning message whenever one of these is used, unless the -nowarn command-line option is used. It is recommended that programs be modified to eliminate the use of deprecated APIs, **though there are no current plans to remove such APIs** – with the exception of JVMDI and JVMPI – entirely from the system.

Even in its [How and When To Deprecate APIs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html), nothing is being said about a policy regarding actually *removing* the deprected APIs...

---

Update 10 years later, the new [JDK9+ **Enhanced Deprecation**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/enhanced-deprecation1.htm#JSCOR-GUID-23B13A9E-2727-42DC-B03A-E374B3C4CE96) clarifies the depreciation policy.
See  [Jens Bannmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7641/jens-bannmann)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50445603/6309) for more details.
This is also detailed in this blog post by [Vojtěch Růžička](https://twitter.com/vojtechruzicka), following [criticisms on JEP 277](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/22/jep-277-enhanced-deprecation-is-nice-but-heres-a-much-better-alternative/).

> The convention for JDK is that once a JDK API is marked as `forRemoval=true` in a certain Java version, **it will be removed in the directly following major Java release**.
>   That means - when something is marked as `forRemoval=true` in Java 9, it is supposed to be completely removed in Java 10.
>   **Keep that in mind when using API marked for removal.**
>
> Note that this convention applies only to JDK itself and third-party libraries are free to choose any convention they see fit.

Comment: Even though they are unlikely to be removed, it is important to note why they have been deprecated.

Usually it is because a method or class does not behave as expected in certain situations. This means that by using a deprecated method or class you risk introducing errors into your code.

Answer (score 13):

They're not going away.  That said, they're usually deprecated because a) they're dangerous ala Thread.stop(), or b) there is a better or at least more accepted way to do it.  Usually deprecated method javadoc will give you a hint as to the better way.  In your case, Calendar is the recommended way to do this.

While it's conceivable that they will be removed at some point in the future, I wouldn't bet on it.  If anyone ever forks Java however, they'll probably be the first thing to go...

Answer (score 7):

One problem is you'll see lots of compiler warnings about using deprecated methods. If you also use deprecations to gradually phase out your own code, the compiler warnings will get lost in the noise and lose significance.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

[As of JDK 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), all original `java.util.Date` methods still exist, but these and other APIs can now be [explicitly marked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/enhanced-deprecation1.htm) for removal. Many other deprecated APIs have been removed recently.

## Full Answer

Before JDK 9, no deprecated API in the JDK was ever removed (see [20 Years Of Java Deprecation](https://www.azul.com/20-years-java-deprecation/)). That release, as part of a feature called [Enhanced Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/enhanced-deprecation1.htm), introduced the `@Deprecated(forRemoval=true)` flag and added it to [dozens of previously deprecated APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#forRemoval).

Also, for the first time in the language's history, JDK 9 **removed** APIs ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/11/latestSpec/#APIs-removed) from the Java SE 9 Specification) which had been deprecated by JDK 8 due to being an obstacle for modularization.

Since then, each JDK release has removed further APIs which were previously marked for removal, most releases have also added the `forRemoval` flag to previously deprecated APIs or added entirely new for-removal deprecations (see table below).

### Key takeaways

1. Deprecated-for-removal APIs are very likely to be removed soon. **Do take this seriously.** While they may not be removed in the next release (e.g. `Thread.stop()` marked `forRemoval` in JDK 9, but was not removed before JDK 11), it can happen quickly.
2. **No deprecated API is safe** as even APIs that have long been deprecated could be removed quite quickly now: one JDK release sets the `forRemoval` flag, the following one removes the API. For example, the APIs that were removed by JDK 10 have been deprecated for at least 20 years (since JDK 1.2), so long that some people may now be surprised.
3. Nowadays, **deprecations and removal happen much more quickly** as Oracle [switched to a 6-month release cycle](https://adtmag.com/articles/2018/03/21/java-10.aspx) with JDK 10.

### Notable removals & proposals

| Release | Removed | Deprecated since | Proposed for removal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **JDK 10** March 2018 | Some APIs in the `SecurityManager` and `Runtime` classes ([full list](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/10/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 1.2 | `java.security.acl` package, `finalize()` methods on certain I/O classes, several other previously deprecated APIs ([full list](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/10/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |
| **JDK 11** September 2018 | `Thread.destroy()` and `Thread.stop()`, several other methods and the `Policy` class ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/11/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 9 & 10 | `java.util.jar.Pack200` APIs ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/11/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |
| **JDK 12** March 2019 | `finalize()` methods of certain I/O classes ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/12/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 10 | none |
| **JDK 13** September 2019 | `Runtime.traceInstructions()` and `Runtime.traceMethodCalls()` ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/13/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 9 | `javax.security.cert` package, methods on `java.lang.String` related to the "text blocks" preview feature and a few other methods ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/13/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |
| **JDK 14** March 2020 | `java.security.acl` package and `java.util.jar.Pack200` APIs ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/14/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 10 & 11 | `Thread.resume()`, `Thread.suspend()` and related `ThreadGroup` methods; `ConstantBootstraps()`, `Modifier()` and `ToolProvider()` constructors ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/14/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |
| **JDK 15** September 2020 | `ConstantBootstraps()` and `Modifier()` constructors ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/15/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 14 | `java.rmi.activation` package ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/15/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |
| **JDK 16** March 2021 | `ToolProvider()` constructor ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/16/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 14 | Constructors of primitive wrapper classes such as `Integer`, `Double` or `Boolean`; `ThreadGroup` methods `destroy()`, `stop()`, `isDaemon()` and friends; `URLDecoder()` constructor; `finalize()` methods of certain color-related AWT classes ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/16/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |
| **JDK 17** September 2021 | `java.rmi.activation` package, `URLDecoder()` constructor ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/17/latestSpec/#APIs-removed)) | JDK 15 & 16 | `java.applet` package, `java.lang.SecurityManager` and related APIs such as `checkAccess()` on `Thread`/`ThreadGroup` ([full list](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/17/latestSpec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal)) |

Comment: Nice update on this 9+ years-old question. I have updated my own answer and referenced your own for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

Well, "not gone yet" and "never going away" are two very different things.  Thats the whole point of deprecation.  They can go away with any future release.  Using them is an at your own risk proposition.  Just be aware that some future release of the JDK may leave your code in an unusable state.

Answer (score 3):

I have a better recommendation: rather than telling him to use `Calendar`, you should switch to either [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or [JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/nonav/doc-2008-08-04/index.html)'s pre-release version.  Some methods on `java.util.Date` may be deprecated, but in my opinion the whole class should be deprecated, along with `Calendar`.  The developers of JSR-310 seem to agree, although I doubt they'll ever bite the bullet and deprecate it.

In no particular order, here's what's wrong with `Date`:

- Its internal representation is milliseconds since the epoch; therefore, cannot represent dates before the epoch.
- All of its useful methods (e.g. `toString`) first normalize the date according to the local timezone.  When working with UTC `Date` instances, this can get *really* annoying; you're forced to use `Calendar` or you will make very bad errors.
- `Calendar`.  It just stinks.  Might win the award for worst API ever.
- Always represents an *instant-in-time*.  No way to represent specific days, or specific years.  No way to represent timezone-less dates values.
- Has almost no useful methods.  See e.g. JodaTime's fluent interface for doing date arithmetic.
- Should have been named `Datetime`, considering that it is one.

Comment: Joda Time is fine but it's not like it lacks awfulness. Creating a DateTime using new DateTime(null) tries to do something useful by generating the current date but in practice only every creates bugs where people forget to check for null. And its own equivalent of the calendar API is full of questionable things which don't quite align with reality (like year 0 existing.) I wonder if JSR-310 is going to make it all sane or just leave us with yet another quirky API.

Comment: `Date` represents dates before the epoch just fine when the millisecond value is negative. http://ideone.com/RAGK08

Answer (score 2):

If the deprecated methods went away, they could break existing code.

While maintaining a clean API is important, the deprecated methods aren't getting in anyone's way.  Sure, there are now better ways to do things, so new methods replace old ones.  But there wouldn't be any gain made (besides a cleaner API) by getting rid of the old ones.

Think of "deprecated" as meaning "outdated", but not necessarily "on the chopping block".

Comment: I hope the core API doesn't use its own deprecated methods.

Answer (score 2):

Deprecated features features that are superseded and should be avoided.  Although they remain in the JDK, they are discouraged as there are better methods available.  The methods are left in the API to support backward compatibility, but should generally be avoided as they could be removed in future versions of the API.

It is technically ok to use deprecated methods, but generally the reason it was deprecated in the first place was that a better/faster/cleaner API has been developed.

Answer (score 1):

Sun tend to be extremely paranoid when it comes to changes that impact backwards compatibility, so I wouldn't expect to see the methods go away any time soon.

But deprecated methods **could** go away at any time in the future, and are normally deprecated for a reason - either because they're unreliable, because they have unpleasant side effects, or simply because there's a better or more elegant way of doing things. The JavaDoc for the method will normally detail which of these is the case and what the acceptable way of carrying out the same operation is these days. Quite frequently the deprecated method will have been replaced with an implementation that calls the 'correct' method anyway, so you're just adding a level of indirection anyway.

You'll also have plenty of compilation warnings if you use these methods, which could be reason enough to avoid them in itself...

Answer (score 1):

I've definitely seen deprecated functions go away - from old versions of Java to the current (I started on 1.1, and some stuff distinctly DID NOT WORK in 1.4).

Other languages handle deprecation differently - Python has been known in the past, for example, to remove deprecated functionality after just a release or two.