# Will deprecated items in Java be removed

Tags: java, deprecated

We know that there are several deprecated items in Java.

Will they be removed? 
Have any deprecated items *ever* been removed from Java?

Comment: API doc stated clearly that which methods are deprecated. Compiler will generate warnings too.

Comment: Probably not anytime soon, not in the short run. Deprecated classes and methods from 1.3 are still working, the only thing the compiler does is throw a warning. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [When are API methods marked "deprecated" actually going to go away?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314540/when-are-api-methods-marked-deprecated-actually-going-to-go-away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will they be removed?

Unlikely since java has always been about maintaining backward compability, but it can happen. I see deprecations as a warning that the API is either unreliable or somehow seriously flawed.
([Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) has several of these).

> Has any of the deprecated items in the past has been removed from java?

AFAIC not removed but never implemented `Thread.destroy()`, as it was along with several other Thread methods inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked [elsewhere](http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/504817-how-many-deprecated-methods-have-been-removed).

Quite frankly, what the Java team usually do, is to deprecate the method and remove its implementation to the suggested method instead. The deprecated method is just an unimplemented method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

You can see that it says

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

So a deprecated method or class is basically a older method or class that is discouraged from being used as there are newer more logical ways to perform that action.

***Will these methods ever be removed?***

Probably not. It will continue to work as before the deprecation, you just have to deal with the pesky warning. In order to keep older programs still running correctly that aren't being updated, almost all deprecated classes and methods won't be removed solely for that reason.

> Deprecated APIs are interfaces that are supported only for backwards compatibility. The javac compiler generates a warning message whenever one of these is used, unless the -nowarn command-line option is used. It is recommended that programs be modified to eliminate the use of deprecated APIs, though there are no current plans to remove such APIs – with the exception of JVMDI and JVMPI – entirely from the system.

**Have any deprecated items been removed?**

In the java.* class, no. There have been a few changes in the javax.* class but in regular java there has never been a deprecated method or class removed.