# Has ever anything been removed from the standard Java API?

Tags: java, api

According to the [glossary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html#deprecation), deprecation allows to remove something from the API. Has this ever happened to the standard API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314540/when-are-api-methods-marked-deprecated-actually-going-to-go-away

Comment: I just searched for "deprecated java api" and came up with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html). Is this what you were looking for? Note: Using deprecated code generates a warning, not an error, so you can still use deprecated code if you *really* want to.

Comment: But these classes haven't been removed, just deprecated.

Comment: a list of "API elements" which were actually removed because they were so bad or dangerous

Comment: @arshajii True. I was going to add a note stating as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to my knowledge, no public method in Java has ever been removed.  Methods that are badly designed and shouldn't be used anymore are marked as deprecated but so far have never been removed.

This is probably because they (Sun, Oracle, JSR community etc) don't want to break old code that relies on these methods.

Comment: Please consider updating this answer. In the meantime, stuff _was_ removed from the JDK - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50445603/7641