# Adding/Subtracting 5 seconds from Java Date - Showing deprected warning

Tags: java, datetime

I want to add 5 seconds to current time

```
    Date date = new Date();

    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds()+ 5);
    System.out.println("old Value is: "+date);
    System.out.println("New Value is: "+ date);
```

It generates the correct output exactly what I needed as:

```
Old Value is: Thu Apr 17 14:10:33 PKT 2014
New Value is: Thu Apr 17 14:10:38 PKT 2014
```

but it gives me a warning error message as

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method getSeconds() from the type Date is deprecated
    - The method setSeconds(int) from the type Date is 
     deprecated
```

What this means. Is it safe to ignore this warning? if not then how to handle it?

Comment: [When are API methods marked “deprecated” actually going to go away?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/314540/3309790) may help you.

Answer (score 9):

you can use `date.setTime(date.getTime() + 5000)`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. Calendar is the best solution you are looking at.

```
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                             .parse("2014-04-17 14:53:25");
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)-5));

System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Out put:

```
Thu Apr 17 14:53:20 IST 2014
```

Answer (score 3):

`deprecated` means that this method should't be used anymore because it can be removed from the Java language in favor of some other method (it probably won't be removed but it's not the preferable way of doing things anymore). [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getSeconds%28%29) suggests you to use `Calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)` which is what you should use in your code.

Note that from Java 8 you can use `LocalDateTime#getSecond` method again.

Comment: Andy suggested `date.setTime(date.getTime() + 5000)` and it works with no warning messages. Actually I want to work with Date object. Is it ok to use `date.setTime(date.getTime() + 5000)` instead for going to Calendar object ?

Comment: In this simple case it is, however in case of some more advanced date arithmetic it might be necessary to use `Calendar` class.

Comment: Also by using `Calendar` you will get your code more readable because you are not adding some magical numbers to your date but you explicitly say what is being added to what.

Comment: Actually I will need to store the date in XML file in xml datetime format by `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Which I am currently performing  `SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");` How to do this for `calendar`.  And beside xml format, I will also need date comparison operations on date. Does the `Calendar` is still best option for me?

Comment: a)You can do it the same way via `Calendar#getTime()`. b) http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

Answer (score 3):

**Java 8** has completly different time-api and makes handling dates a lot easier. [Here's an article](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/24-a-new-date-and-time-api-for-jdk-8)

With **Java Versions 5-7** (everything below should not be used IMHO) you should use Calendar ([as Petr suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23129252/2316112))
If you are allowed to use third-party APIs, you should definitly take a look at [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 2):

showing deprecated warning that  means 
there is some **better** way available in java to do so.

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

The future visitors of this page are recommended to use ***java.time*** API. The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Just local time:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ZoneId.systemDefault() returns the time-zone of JVM. Change it as per your
        // requirement e.g. to ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalTime localTimeNow = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(localTimeNow);

        // After 5 seconds
        LocalTime localTimeAfter5Sec = localTimeNow.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(localTimeAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

**Local date & time:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ZoneId.systemDefault() returns the time-zone of JVM. Change it as per your
        // requirement e.g. to ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalDateTime ldtNow = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(ldtNow);

        // After 5 seconds
        LocalDateTime ldtAfter5Sec = ldtNow.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(ldtAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

**Date & time with timezone:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ZoneId.systemDefault() returns the time-zone of JVM. Change it as per your
        // requirement e.g. to ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdtNow);

        // After 5 seconds
        ZonedDateTime zdtAfter5Sec = zdtNow.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(zdtAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

**An instantaneous point on the time-line:**

[`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) models a single instantaneous point on the time-line and is independent of timezone. It's most commonly used functions, `toEpochMilli` and `ofEpochMilli` are used to convert an instant to the number of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, and milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z to an instant respectively. Note that `Z` stands for `Zulu` and represents `UTC+00:00`.

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This moment
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now);

        // Moment after 5 sec
        Instant momentAfter5Sec = now.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(momentAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### *Joda-time*

An excerpt from the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Just local time:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DateTimeZone.getDefault() returns the time-zone of JVM. Change it as per your
        // requirement e.g. to DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")
        LocalTime localTimeNow = LocalTime.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(localTimeNow);

        // After 5 seconds
        LocalTime localTimeAfter5Sec = localTimeNow.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(localTimeAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

**Local date & time:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DateTimeZone.getDefault() returns the time-zone of JVM. Change it as per your
        // requirement e.g. to DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")
        LocalDateTime ldtNow = LocalDateTime.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(ldtNow);

        // After 5 seconds
        LocalDateTime ldtAfter5Sec = ldtNow.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(ldtAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

**Date & time with timezone:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DateTimeZone.getDefault() returns the time-zone of JVM. Change it as per your
        // requirement e.g. to DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")
        DateTime dtNow = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(dtNow);

        // After 5 seconds
        DateTime dtAfter5Sec = dtNow.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(dtAfter5Sec);
    }
}
```

**An instantaneous point on the time-line:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        System.out.println(now);

        // After 5 seconds
        DateTime after5Sec = now.plusSeconds(5);
        System.out.println(after5Sec);
    }
}
```

**Legacy API:**

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the milliseconds from the `Epoch of January 1, 1970`. When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time calculated from this milliseconds value. Since `java.util.Date` does not have timezone information, it applies the timezone of your JVM and displays the same. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFomrat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);// -5 if you want to subtract
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

***java.time.Instant* as the bridge between the legacy and the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();

        // Now you can convert instant to other types of java.time e.g.
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

For whatsoever purpose, if you want to convert `instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`:

```
Date dateTime = Date.from(instant);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest solution:**

if it is the **current date** use:

```
Long seconds= 10; //update in seconds 

//seconds*1000 to convert second to millisecond
Date dateAfterUpdation = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (seconds*1000) );
```

**For a specific Date:**

```
Long seconds= 10;   //update in seconds
//seconds*1000 to convert second to millisecond
Date dateAfterUpdation = new Date(oldDate.getTime() - (seconds*1000) );
```

Similarly, you can add or subtract any amount of time by this trick.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here is some example code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3. The bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome, and should be avoided.

Unlike a java.util.Date, a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object has an assigned time zone.

When specifying time zones, use a [proper time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Avoid the three or four letter codes as they are neither standardized nor unique.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); // Has no time zone. Misnamed, as it contains both a date and a time portions.

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Karachi" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime fiveSecondsAgo = dateTime.minusSeconds( 5 );
java.util.Date date2 = fiveSecondsAgo.toDate();
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "fiveSecondsAgo: " + fiveSecondsAgo );
System.out.println( "date2: " + date2 );
```

When run…

```
date: Thu Apr 17 14:44:01 PDT 2014
dateTime: 2014-04-18T02:44:01.773+05:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-04-17T21:44:01.773Z
fiveSecondsAgo: 2014-04-18T02:43:56.773+05:00
date2: Thu Apr 17 14:43:56 PDT 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use apache `DateUtils`.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

DateUtils.addSeconds(now, 5); // Add 5 seconds.
DateUtils.addSeconds(now, -5); // Subtracting 5 seconds
```

You can also add/subtract minutes, hours, and so on...