# Mark deprecated method ussing ActiveSupport::Deprecation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecated, activesupport

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293981/best-practice-to-mark-deprecated-code-in-ruby) is explained what to do to make a simple warning (but do not log trace so is not so useful) and there is a bunch of methods to make this, but I found no guides.

How do I use ActiveSupport::Deprecation to mark a old_method as deprecated and call other new_method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993876/mark-deprecated-method-ussing-activesupportdeprecation/6010612#6010612) says, it can be done with
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(target_module, *deprecated_methods)

where:

- `target_module` is the module or class where the method belongs.
- `deprecated_methods` is an array of symbols.

In the last methods can be given options to customize the deprecation message.

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(target_module, :old_method, \
    :other_old_method => :new_method, :another_old_method => "custom message")
```

This example shows the default message when old_method is called, give a comment to "*use new_method instead*", in the second one, and the custom message with :another_old_method.

**Notes**: The deprecated methods should be defined (before) and will be executed. The :new_method is **not** called automatically. (there are more options, but I don't know them)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into `lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb` for an example.

Comment: What do you mean? This is a file which shows, how Rails' uses deprecation. In essence, what you need in your code, is to call ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(target_module, *method_names), and that's it.

Comment: this file don't explain how to to give options, i realized that if i use `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(target_module, :deprecated_method => :new_method)` It use new method in the message given. There are other options, but they are not well documented. Thanks.