# How to mark a class as Deprecated in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, deprecation-warning

In Ruby (and even more so: Rails) it is [easy to mark methods as deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293981/best-practice-to-mark-deprecated-code-in-ruby).

But how can I mark an entire class as deprecated? I want to raise a warning whenever a class is used:

```
class BillingMethod
end

BillingMethod.new #=> DEPRECATION WARNING: the class BillingMethod is deprecated. Use PaymentMethod instead.
```

Or when it gets used in inheritance:

```
class Sofort < BillingMethod
end

Sofort.new #=> DEPRECATION WARNING: the class BillingMethod is deprecated. Use PaymentMethod instead.
```

Or, when used in nested classes:

```
class BillingMethod::Sofort < BillingMethod
end

BillingMethod::Sofort.new #=> DEPRECATION WARNING: the class BillingMethod is deprecated. Use PaymentMethod instead.
```

I would think that a [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_eval)-block would be the place where to stick such a warning. Is that the correct place? Or are there better methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`const_missing`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_missing)  to deprecate constants, and, by extension, classes.

`const_missing` is being invoked when an undefined constant is referenced.

```
module MyModule

  class PaymentMethod
    # ...
  end

  def self.const_missing(const_name)
    super unless const_name == :BillingMethod
    warn "DEPRECATION WARNING: the class MyModule::BillingMethod is deprecated. Use MyModule::PaymentMethod instead."
    PaymentMethod
  end
end
```

This allows existing code that references `MyModule::BillingMethod` to continue to work, and warns the user about their use of the deprecated class.

It's the best I've seen so far for the deprecating class purpose.

Comment: In your example, how would `const_missing` be fired, when you've defined it just above?

Comment: @berkes the first part should not be there, typo

Comment: In the `const_missing` method, what is the `PaymentMethod\n end` exactly achieving there?

Comment: `const_missing` is being invoked when a reference is made to an undefined constant in module. It returns a value (`PaymentMethod` in this case) to be used for that constant.

Comment: It seems to me, that the last `end` just before closing the `const_missing` -method is superflous and incorrect. In Ruby 2.1.x it gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 11):

You may want to have a look at [`Deprecate`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Deprecate.html) which is part of Ruby's Standard Library:

```
require 'rubygems'

class BillingMethod
  extend Gem::Deprecate

  class << self
    deprecate :new, "PaymentMethod.new", 2016, 4
  end

  # Will be removed April 2016, use `PaymentMethod.new` instead
  def initialize 
    #...
  end
end
```

Using the `deprecated` method would result in a warning like this:

```
BillingMethod.new
# => NOTE: BillingMethod#new is deprecated; use PaymentMethod.new instead. It will be removed on or after 2016-04-01.
# => BillingMethod#new called from file_name.rb:32.
```

Comment: That will only raise warnings when an object gets initialized. Not when a class is used as parent or used in a nested class tree. Or am I missing an important detail?

Comment: @berkes You can use the above to deprecate the `inherited` hook (class method), thereby deprecating inheritance: `class BillingMethod; class << self; deprecate :inherited, :none, 2016, 4; end; end`. Inheriting from BillingMethod should now issue the deprecation warning.

Comment: The code in the example is wrong.  Because `:new` is a class-method, you need to wrap the `extend...deprecate` lines in a `class << self` block.

Comment: @berkes, I fixed my example.

Answer (score -2):

Why not do it this way:

```
def initialize(*args)
  warn "DEPRECATION WARNING: ..."
  super
end
```

Comment: Author wants to show warning on all class usages (e.g. inheritance), not only new objects creating.